# Implement IActivitySource in bot to retrive activities history

Tags: c#, botframework, direct-line-botframework

I'm trying to implement ***Microsoft.Bot.Builder.History.IActivitySource*** in my bot to retrive activities previosly saved in my SQL database (I've used **IActivityLogger** to save them earlier). The question is: Where is this interface used in the bot framework to invoke my class and return the history of activities of a conversation?

I'm using Directline to invoke my bot but when I load a conversation by "id" it is retrieved from de DL caché and my bot is not even called...

Comment: Have you taken a look at this https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Azure/blob/master/CSharp/Library/Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Azure/TableLogger.cs

Comment: @JasonSowers Yes, my class is implemented that way, the problem is the Bot framework is not calling the methods "IActivitySource.Activities" and "IActivitySource.WalkActivitiesAsync" from anywhere...